# How to check for zeros in a list in sml

Tags: sml

I am struggling to create a function that will return the product of each element in a given list excluding zeros. The following function will correctly return the product of a list, but will not exclude zeroes.

```
fun mult_nonzero(xs) = 
    case xs of [] => 0 
    | (x :: xs') => x * mult_nonzero(xs');
```

How do I add a check for zeroes?

Comment: Hint: add another case.

Comment: That function always returns zero, even when there are none in the input. (Don't retype code – copy and paste.)

Comment: Note that `0! = 2^0 = 1`. Empty products are not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the pattern matching directly in the function argument:

```
fun mult_nonzero [] = ...
  | mult_nonzero (x::xs) = ...
```

Just as you can match on the argument being either an empty list, or a list with at least one element, you can also match on the first element being something specific but introducing yet another function case with a pattern and a body. I'd place it in the middle:

```
fun mult_nonzero [] = ...
  | mult_nonzero ... = ...
  | mult_nonzero (x::xs) = x * mult_nonzero xs
```

But dealing with zeroes in the list is not your only problem.

Your base case being 0 has a problem that you will discover if you make some simple test cases:

```
val test_mult_nonzero_1 = mult_nonzero [5] = 5
val test_mult_nonzero_2 = mult_nonzero [5, 3] = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foldl (or foldr). If you're unfamiliar with fold, it's worth familiarizing yourself with it.

```
fun mult_nonzero([]) = 0
  | mult_nonzero(xs) = foldl (fn (a, b) => if a = 0 then b else a*b) 1 xs
```